# What are diamond cut alloy wheels?

Tags: wheels, theory

I'm thinking of buying a new car, and one of the options it has is diamond cut alloy wheels.

What's the difference between normal and diamond cut alloys?

Comment: This question seems fraught with opinion, as Martin alludes to ... not closing yet, but leaning that way.

Comment: I really should know better! revised my question

Comment: Sounds like marketing BS to me.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing "wrong" with them, except they cost more, the finish doesn't last long, and you can only refurbish the finish a couple of times.

But don't let that put you off, if you really want them.

More information [here](https://www.thewheelspecialist.co.uk/wheel-finishes/diamond-cutting/). The fact that that company doesn't *guarantee* diamond cut finish, even though they will do it, might also be relevant!

Answer (score 1):

I'd never heard of this before. Apparently a diamond cut wheel is simply one that has been machined (no diamonds involved, as far as I can tell) to be shiny. They get clear-coated after the machining.

It removes a tiny bit of material (if done properly). Perhaps your friend is trying to save you the embarrassment of driving around with shiny wheels. Just kidding, I have no idea how polishing a wheel could harm it (assuming it was done properly).

It's your car, if you like them, do what you like!

Comment: I believe it is a diamond tipped cutting tool that is used.

Comment: @HandyHowie - that may be true, but none of the vendors of diamond cutting equipment mention anything about diamond cutting tools. I think they are referring to the shine/reflection. I could be wrong, but it seems like if they were actually using diamond tools, they'd mention it specifically. "...a thin layer is cut from the alloy using a specialist CNC lathe." Wouldn't you think they'd mention diamond tools?

Comment: First place I looked - https://www.mikebrewermotors.com/blog/introducing-our-diamond-cutting-alloy-wheel-machine - "Instead, we use a special machine with a diamond tip tool (and yes, there are actual diamonds in the cutting tool!) to remove a layer of metal from the wheel that is thinner than a sheet of aluminum foil."

Comment: Well, that makes one!

Comment: Here is a second, if you need more evidence - https://www.austinconsultants.co.uk/project/diamond-cut-refinishing/  "The wheel is painted and then cut back using a special diamond coated cutting tip to expose the metal and provide a high-quality finish"

Comment: And a third -https://www.diamond-wheels.net/diamond-cut-wheels.php " Diamond cutting is also known as single point diamond turning(S.P.D.T) or diamond turning it is a process where the alloy wheel is placed in a lathe and a small layer of the of the wheel surface is machined off the alloy wheel with a diamond pointed cutting tool."

Comment: There are loads of examples - http://www.auto-wheels.co.uk/diamond-cut-wheel-refurbishment/ "In order to do this we have to use a diamond tipped tool on a lathe which gives us a better cut of the alloy and therefore a sparkly finish"

Comment: http://www.lepsons.com/are-there-any-limitations-to-what-can-be-refurbished/ ..................................

Answer (score 0):

It is only about appearance and diamond cut is in style this year. The aluminum cast wheels are coated ( usually black) then a diamond , or equal , cutting tool trims off the high areas giving a black and silver wheel. Diamond ( or exceptionally hard)  cutting tools are used because cast aluminum typically contains about 10% silicon ; the aluminum and silicon combine to make some very hard intermetallic compound which will wear away most cutting tools quickly.